# EC2 instance - sending user data - is it secure?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a Amazon EC2 instance and the purpose of this instance is to do a computation based on some medical information. I'm booting the instance from Java via the Amazon Java API (`RunInstanceRequest`). I'm giving the EC2 Instance some user data (e.g patient id) that the instance needs to do the computation.

```
request.setUserData(getMyUserData());
```

I'm just wondering how secure is to do this - is this info. encrypted somehow ?

Comment: "Secure" in what context?  In transit across the network during the method call? To processes on the instance?  External users on the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1697 The article goes over some of the basic security that amazon has. It doesn't mention anything specifically about user data but I assume that its relatively secure. I'd be careful if your passing any sensitive user information, passing a user id should be ok but i wouldn't be passing passwords or credit card information etc with it.

If you're concerned about the security you can always encrypt the data yourself and decrypt the data when it reaches your instance.

Comment: "I assume it's relatively secure" are fatal words.

Answer (score 2):

This is not secure. The EC2 operators have full access to your data. Perhaps the data is encrypted on the way to EC2, which would prevent interceptors from getting your data, but EC2 will still get it.

If you care about security, you should either send only encrypted output of your data to EC2, and decrypt it locally after retrieving it, or simply buy your own machine and put the data there.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 user data is very much insecure. All AWS instances have access to a metadata URL where user data is one of the available pieces of metadata. Any process on the server that's able to do a HTTP request can access this and pull the user data in plain text.